# Radio Button is not checked if I click an anchor in its label area

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, radio-button, angular-ui-router

Currently I've the following phenomenon:

Radio Button ist not checked if I klick an anchor (in the case below Menu 1 to n) in its label area . The label area is styled as grey background and has a thin black border. Radio Button is away from the visible area `{position: absolut; top: top: -9999px;}`

If I remove the anchor, everything is fine again, but that's not the desired result.

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in my.navigation.menu">

    <input type="radio" 
          name="myNavi" 
          class="naviRadio " 
          id="navi{{$index}}" 
          ng-checked="$first">

    <label class="navigationItem" for="navi{{$index}}" >
        <a ui-sref="{{item.ui_url}}">{{item.name}}</a>
    </label>

</div>
```

If the label content is linked and I klick on the link:

```
 radio button is not checked.
```

If I click within the label area (gray area behind the link):

```
 radio button is checked
```

**My aim:** If I click the both the link or label area the radio button should be checked.

Comment: so, you want an anchor tag that doesn't behave like an anchor tag .. by the way, calling it a "phenomenon" implies it's somehow unexpected, but this is not unexpected behaviour

Comment: no, I see that completely different: I want a label, that behaves like a label independent of its content :)

Comment: I think you want to put the whole input tag inside of that label tag :\

Comment: I've tried that too already

Comment: @krozaine - you can use label tags as in the question, or as you've suggested - both are valid

Comment: I've seen that already working somewhere, unfortunately I cannot find the web page. Please don't tell me a story ;) I don't care about the validity in the case above.

Comment: actually, ignore my previous "validity" argument - it was not accurate :p

Comment: have you tried putting the input element within the label tag?

Comment: Yes, it did not work. There are 3 variables (radio, label, anchor) and 2^3 = 8 Possibilities -> I've tried all of them.

Comment: Do you have a click handler on the anchor? I suspect it's doing `event.stopPropagation()`, which is preventing the click from bubbling out to the label.

Comment: z-index could be the culprit, check that.

Comment: no klick events it is simply a `href="#/dashboard/sa"` from angular-ui-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the `<a>` tag

```
onclick='this.parentElement.click();'
```

---

and the following style, also to the `<a>` tag

```
style="display:inline-block;width:100%;"
```